# Cloudbees allow wildcart domains add/remove by users

Tags: cloudbees

Why Cloudbees doesn't allow wildcart domains by default? Heroku makes really easy for user to add/remove wildcart domains like *.me.com. I filed a ticket over 24 hours but still there is no one trying to resolve that ticket.

Comment: Hi, this ticket hasn't been neglected, just forwarded internally to RUN engineering without user feedback, sorry for that.
wildcard domain name is not yet integrated in web UI, as this is not such a common request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcard SSL domains are supported by RUN@cloud, however it is not exposed in the user interface.

As to why it's not in the UI - it's not a common request, and as such hasn't inflicted enough pain on support to warrant implementing a user configurable interface for it as yet.

There is further information on Custom Application Domains, wildcard domains and how to raise a request with the appropriate information at https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Custom+Application+Domains

Comment: Yes, wildcard domains for SSL are there, have been using them for over a year now ourselves. But I guess it's not possible for non-SSL.